# Page in the Help Center describing how to close and delete your own question

Tags: feature-request, vote-to-close, help-center, vote-to-delete, help-center-proposed

I didn't see any clear description of how to close or delete your own question.

There's already a page describing [why and how are some questions deleted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/deleted-questions), which says this:

> Questions can also be deleted by the community. Moderators can delete
>   any question, and users with [sufficient reputation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/privileges/moderator-tools) can cast delete
>   votes on closed questions. It takes 3 votes, minimum, to delete a
>   closed question. However, the number of delete votes required scales
>   to the number of votes on the question and all its answers. Questions
>   that have been closed within the past 48 hours cannot be deleted, so
>   as to allow for editing and possible [reopening](https://meta.stackexchange.com/helpcenter/reopen-questions).

Unfortunately there's no hint about whether that also relates to your **own** questions.

So there should be at least a hint about that on that page (for all Stack Exchange sites, of course). Even better IMO would be to have a separate Help Center page describing this in detail as it's done for [answering your own question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer). Title of that page could be 'Can I delete my own question?'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Might add this, because it would save some confusion (and probably a dozen or so emails to our support line each week). The help center was seeded from the community curated FAQ, linking back to it for additional help, but we knew that there'd be more 'quick answers' that would be needed in the help center.

I've created [help-center-proposed](/questions/tagged/help-center-proposed) for things that are well explained in the FAQ but simply not discovered very easily, similar to this. Now, before using this shiny new tag on a bunch of stuff, it's probably not going to go in 90% of the time - so use it only when hitting a wall of frustration trying to do something you feel should have been more obvious.

There's probably .. a dozen or so more caveats that should be better explained there, with more to come as new features roll out.

Answer (score 3):

A hint would be good. However, I don't see a need for a separate page because the [Help Center page for deleted questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/deleted-questions) already links to the FAQ post where related details are provided. Help Center page mentions the following:

> The community-curated FAQ contains more details about deleted posts.

It links to [How does deleting work? What can cause a post to be deleted, and what does that actually mean? What are the criteria for deletion?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/how-does-deleting-work-what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that)

Comment: Yeah; originally, the help center was supposed to be a sort of "Stack Exchange Primer", with the [meta-tag:faq] for all the meaty stuff. We all put a ton of work into that faq you linked to, and while it's a bit on the long side I don't know that it'd be possible to get the same information into the help center without making it *even longer*.